# MVVM pattern basics

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm

A very common scenario. We have:

```cs
double _H;
public double H
{
  get { return _H; }
  set
  {
    if (_H == value) return;
    _H = value;
    SomeMethod("H");     
    //Inside SomeMethod's body we calculate some other properties among other things, 
    //and we call their corresponding base.RaisePropertyChanged. ALSO we 
    //RECALCULATE the freshly set H and we WANT to call base.RaisePropertyChanged("H")
    //to "propagate" the changed value back to the View control that called the setter 
    //portion of the property in the first place!  
    }
}
```

**Answer :**
Look at Jay's post. Key concept to keep from this question: **Asynchronous Invocation** as Jay mentioned.

**Some more details (maybe repetitive or irrelevant) :** I have a NumericUpDown control and I click on it's button to change its value. The problem is that I want to recalculate the given value and see if it is permitted (validation in view-model). But I cant push back the value that is being sent from control to the set portion of the property. The first solution which came in mind is to trigger the `ValueChanged` event in the View and call `SomeMethod("H")` from there. Not good though.

In reality there are about 10 NumericUpDown controls. The value of each represent a dimension of a geometric shape. So, changes in one value, can alter the other dimensions. The problem arises when the calculation determines that the value just given must change also (if you understand what I mean).
Also some relevant XAML code:

```
<l:NumericUpDown Value="{Binding H}" Maximum="{Binding MaxSide, Mode=OneTime}" 
 Grid.Column="7"/>
```

Comment: Try putting `base.RaisePropertyChanged("H")` below the method that calculates the value for `H`.

Comment: @aligray No it's not THAT simple. It has something to do with binding. The problem is that the control doesnt get notified by the `raisepropertychanged`, since it is in the "mode" of sending the value. `raisepropertychanged` works only when the "set portion" is called from another control, e.g. an independent button.

Comment: Is the property bound to a textbox?

Comment: It is bound to the NumericUpDown of the WPF Extended Toolkit (in the end in the texbox PART of the control, but i dont want to mess with the codeplex .dll)

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting your binding `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged`?  I still think you need to move where you raise the event from as @aligray suggested

Comment: I have tried, it doesnt work. `I still think you need to move where you raise the event from as @aligray suggested` You mean the first comment? I actuall put the raiseevent inside the method i call. This is not the problem.

Comment: Do you get any binding errors in the `output` window? (Assuming you're using VS)

Comment: No i dont get any binding errors.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through all of the code in the `setter` with the debugger?

Comment: Everything works when i m changing the value by using another (indepentent) control as I said.

Comment: What type is the control that it works with?

Comment: In reality there are about 10 NumericUpDown controls. The value of each represent a dimension of a geometric shape. So, changes in one value, can alter the other dimensions. The problem arises when the calculation determines that the value just given must change also (if you understand what I mean)

Comment: I think you should show the xaml for your binding expression. I think the problem might be there. (did you make sure to bind it with TwoWay mode?)

Comment: @abdou. Its TwoWay. I put some XAML.

Comment: The problem looks to be `Mode = OneTime`.

Comment: @Dimitris: it doesn't appear to be "TwoWay"! if it isn't specified, I believe it defaults to OneWay.

Comment: It actually depends by the control. There is no such default. In this case the default is TwoWay. And by the way, the question has been asnwered. See the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the Dispatcher to either force a refresh or to raise the property change notification outside of the context of the setter (asynchronous invocation).

So, instead of

```
base.OnPropertyChanged("H");
```

…you'd do

```
Action action = () => base.OnPropertyChanged("H");
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
```